# How to remove cycles from a resistance network

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have a resistance network represented by an undirected graph whose edges represent resistance values. Some nodes are called drivers and some nodes are called sinks other nodes are internal nodes. Objective is to compute effective resistance from each driver to each sink. The graph can have cycles, star delta network. So following formula can be used to compute effective resistance.

[Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_analysis_%28electrical_circuits%29#General_form_of_network_node_elimination)

Note that if the graph does not has any cycle then simple DFS traversal will give a driver to each sink effective resistance. But if it has cycles then cycles must be removed. One approach is to copy the graph into a temporary graph then remove all nodes from the temporary graph using the above formula except a driver and a sink. Do this for all driver sink pairs but this approach is very time consuming for large dense graph. I am getting this high run time by storing the graph in either tcl hash table or `std::tr1::unordered_map`.

Do you have any idea on an efficient approach to compute each driver to each sink resistance?

I have one inefficient solution i.e. 
for each driver for each sink
       copy the original graph into a temporary graph
       then remove all nodes from the temporary graph except that source and that sink using the wiki article I mentioned above.
       The final temporary graph will give effective resistance between that source and that sink.
Run time of this solution is not acceptable for large input data so I need better solution.

Comment: The correct approach should be performing [Nodal analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis) instead of graph transformation.

Comment: i didn't check the wiki article but why not compute a spanning tree? the one that DFS produces for example?

Comment: i think you can model this as a `max flow` problem where flow is resistance and compute the routes

Comment: I don't know how to perform nodal analysis on this problem because voltages are not present only the resistance network is given. Also I don't think spanning tree, max flow can solve this problem. Can you explain more how will these solve my problem?

Comment: 1. Assign the source node as 1V and sink node as 0
2. Perform nodal analysis, get the total current `I`
3. `R = V / I = 1 / I`

Answer (score 3):

To compute effective resistance from each driver to each sink, you don't need to perform graph transformation. Instead, you could

1. For each pair of driver and sink, assign the driver node as 1V and the sink node as 0
2. Perform [nodal analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis), which only requires linear equation formulation. And you get the current `I` flow from driver to sink.
3. By definition, effective resistance `R = V / I = 1 / I`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you post algorithmic view as I find it too abstract to work on implementation.

Comment: @doptimusprime What do you mean by "algorithmic view?"

Comment: @doptimusprime You could refer to http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Electric_Circuit_Analysis/Nodal_Analysis for how to formulate nodal analysis into matrix equations. Then you can solve the matrix equation with your favorite library or your own solver.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am assigning bounty to you.

Comment: This solution may take long time for large input size. Do you have an efficient solution?

Comment: @ranjuchhatna How did you solve the system of linear equations during nodal analysis?

Comment: @timrau How can I find the loops in the circuit using an algorithmic so that I can apply KVL to each loop?

Comment: @ranjuchhatna 1. You can find loop by Bellman-Ford algorithm; 2. You _don't_ need to find loop for applying KVL. Just assign one variable to represent voltage for each node, and apply KCL for each node.

Comment: How can I apply KCL at each node from algorithmic point of view?  I have to automate this solution. I could not think of a automated solution using your approach.

Comment: @ranjuchhatna Refer to http://projects-web.engr.colostate.edu/ece-sr-design/AY08/SKIES/Matrices%20&%20Their%20Applications%20(final).pdf which tells you how to derive equation system from circuit and solve the equation system by matrix operations.